# Adding On() event instead of live() event in Jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I'm a bit confused right now, before I changed to Jquery 1.9.1 i used `live()` event to bind events to my buttons on document.ready, but now i am forced to change `.live()` to `.on()` event, and my buttons stopped working. so code i had before could look like :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#button").live('click', buttonEvent);
});
```

and after:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#button").on('click', buttonEvent);
});
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $(document).on('click', '#button', buttonEvent); 
});
```

jQuery `.on()` can be used to delegate events on elements. Its pattern is bit differrent but better.

Answer (score 1):

You can see the changes required on this page [Live to On](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

taken from that page are the following, which demonstrate the syntax changes:

```
1 $("a.offsite").live("click", function(){ alert("Goodbye!"); }); // jQuery 1.3+
2 $(document).delegate("a.offsite", "click", function(){ alert("Goodbye!"); }); // jQuery 1.4.3+
3 $(document).on("click", "a.offsite", function(){ alert("Goodbye!"); }); // jQuery 1.7+
```